Managing artifacts locally
At work I was tasked with evaluating the implementation of a CI/CD workflow for our C# project.
I am using Bitbucket and Jenkins, and I have configured it so that pushing to the repository automatically triggers the project build. Now I am faced with the question of what the do with the artifacts. For now my manager does not want to use a paid service (i.e. Artifactory or Nexus). Is there a common practice/established way for managing artifacts locally.
This is my first time working on CI/CD and no one in the company has experience with it either.

https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-artifactory-documentation/local-repositories

Both Nexus and JFrog have versions that may be suitable, hosted locally, and free. Look into Sonatype Nexus OSS version for example. 
Also -the Apache Archiva project is no longer active, but might still be suitable if you're working locally within a DMZ for instance.

Thanks Peter, I know have Sonatype Nexus OSS running locally
